# Passing this when using lodash throttle with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, lodash

[Working from this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/lodash-throttle-debounce/) I have the following code:

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resizedWindow: _.throttle(this.reset, 200),
    reset(){
      this.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.reset();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizedWindow);
  }
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined

Usually this is to do with `this` and I (usually) know how to fix that. You do something like this:

```
// Replace previous resizeWindow with...
resizedWindow(){
  let vm = this;
  _.throttle(vm.reset, 200);
},
```

But this never fires the `reset` method. I *know* it must be something silly or gap in my understanding of `this` – how can I make this work?

Comment: "this" is undefined because `_.throttle(this.reset, 200)` invokes on object definition even before "exports" assignment is, so reference of "this" is window(or "undefined" in your case because you have strict mode enabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your case `this` is referring to the `window` object. You can move your `resizedWindow` method definition to the `created` hook [as seen here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to have access to `this` as the Vue instance ..

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reset(){
      this.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.resizedWindow = _.throttle(this.reset, 200)
  },
  mounted(){
    this.reset();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizedWindow);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make use of an `IIFE` ..

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resizedWindow() { (_.throttle(this.reset, 200))() },
    reset(){
      this.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.reset();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizedWindow);
  }
}
```